# Got unknown argument class: JSONArray

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to bridge React Native to Android to call an SDK.

I have a method I am adapting for my purposes:

```
@ReactMethod
private void renderProfileSharingUI(ReadableArray args) throws JSONException {
    if (args.length() != 1) {
        this.errorCallback.invoke("renderProfileSharingUI scopes must be provided");
        return;
    }

    JSONArray jsonArgs = convertArrayToJson(args);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.activity, PayPalProfileSharingActivity.class);
    // add codes
    intent.putExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, getOauthScopes(jsonArgs.getJSONArray(0)));
    startActivityForResult(this, intent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING);
}

private static JSONArray convertArrayToJson(ReadableArray readableArray) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < readableArray.size(); i++) {
        switch (readableArray.getType(i)) {
        case Null:
            break;
        case Boolean:
            array.put(readableArray.getBoolean(i));
            break;
        case Number:
            array.put(readableArray.getDouble(i));
            break;
        case String:
            array.put(readableArray.getString(i));
            break;
        case Map:
            array.put(convertMapToJson(readableArray.getMap(i)));
            break;
        case Array:
            array.put(convertArrayToJson(readableArray.getArray(i)));
            break;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Originally, the method called for a JSONArray. React Native passes in a ReadableArray, which I then use the function to convert to a JSONArray.

However, despite this, I am getting the error:

[image: Got unknown argument class: JSONArray]

Now, of course, I am absolutely importing this above:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

This is my React Native side of things:

```
NativeModules.PayPalMobileRN.renderProfileSharingUI(["openid", "email", "address"]).then(
    result => console.log(result)
)
```

Nothing crazy, just passing in an array of scope values.

What exactly is this hiccuping on?

Comment: Hy, how did u solved this issue

Comment: @Sahilbalgotra100 I don't remember off the top of my head - I'll try to take a look at my code from this project sometime today or tomorrow and get back to you